# Wildcard subdomain and subfolders as parameters in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I have a portal site http://www.mysite.com/ where customers sign up and they get their own subdomain version of the site to run my app.
I've set up the wildcard subdomain DNS/VirtualHost etc and got it working.

What I am trying to set up is my htaccess file to pass the wildcard subdomain as a parameter to the app, like this:

```
http://wildcardsubdomain.mysite.com/ -> http://www.mysite.com/app/?dj=wildcardsubdomain
http://wildcardsubdomain.mysite.com/?l=genres -> http://www.mysite.com/app/?dj=wildcardsubdomain&l=genres
```

I accomplished this by having this in my .htaccess file in http://www.mysite.com/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mysite.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://www.mysite.com/app/dj/%1 [P,L]
```

But I need to redirect the admin user URLs as follows and I've gotten stuck with the htaccess code to use inside the /app directory.
What I need is:

```
http://wildcardsubdomain.mysite.com/admin/?l=genres -> http://www.mysite.com/app/admin.php?dj=wildcardsubdomain&l=genres
http://wildcardsubdomain.mysite.com/admin/?l=users -> http://www.mysite.com/app/admin.php?dj=wildcardsubdomain&l=users
```

(the l parameter varies, I've just used users and genres here as an example)

I've tried this inside /app/.htaccess but it hasnt really worked:

```
RewriteRule ^dj/([^/]+)/?$ $2?dj=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php$2?dj=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Can anyone suggest a better rewrite rule?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `QSA` flag, as the `l=genres` gets lost otherwise. You just need an "admin" rule before your other rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mysite.com
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ http://www.mysite.com/app/admin.php?dj=%1 [P,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mysite.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://www.mysite.com/app/dj=%1 [P,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Replaced the main site htaccess with your code which works, but not for the admin links (see my original post.)
The app/ directory htaccess:
`#app original rules
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.html index.php
RewriteRule ^admin admin.php
# my rules
RewriteRule ^dj/([^/]+)/?$ $2?dj=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php$2?dj=$1 [QSA,L]`

Do I need to change my rules in the /app folder htaccess file?